# Android: Add custom option to Chooser Intent

Tags: android

In my android App, I need to allow the user to share some elements. The sharing method that I want to enable are Facebook, twitter and a custom form where the user enters an email and some information, and the app will send the element to this email. The code I have so far is:

```
private void share(List<String> appNames, String imagePath, String text) {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
        Intent share = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        share.setType("image/jpeg");
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(share, 0);
        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()){
            for (ResolveInfo info : resInfo) {
                Intent targetedShare = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                targetedShare.setType("image/jpeg"); // put here your mime type
                for(String nameApp : appNames){
                    if (info.activityInfo.packageName.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp) ||  info.activityInfo.name.toLowerCase().contains(nameApp)) {
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
                        targetedShare.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(imagePath)) );
                        targetedShare.setPackage(info.activityInfo.packageName);
                        targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShare);
                    }
                }

            }

            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.remove(0), getString(R.string.share_dialog_title));
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
            startActivity(chooserIntent);
        }
    }
```

where `appNames` is `private static final String[] sharingMethods = {"face", "twi"};`

This work as expected and allow the user to choose between Facebook and Twitter, but I have no idea how to add a custom activity to the chooser. 
Is that possible or should I build my own chooser activity? Can anybody point me out in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I Understand, you need to show your own custom activity along with the Facebook and Twitter while showing the share dialog by android.

For that, you need to add the action "android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND" in Manifest for that activity, and its mime type. For example :

```
<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

For more info check this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html)

Comment: I managed to add my custom activity to the chooser and I've been able to customize the title that appears at the chooser, but I don't know how to change the icon. Currently, it's shown the App icon, but I want to change it, it that possible?

Comment: Ok, I answer my previous question, for customize the icon I used android:icon="@drawable/icon_custom"> in the activity definition.